# Android design template full screen imageview

Tags: android, templates, interface

I'm not sure where to start here, I've had a google around but I'm not really getting where I want to be.

I want to make an Android application where the whole user interface is just an image, swipe in the left or right direction moves onto the next image

Answer (score 0):

using this example we can detect gestures of moving finger left , right , up and downward

http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2010/01/android-gestures.html

Comment: I've used gestures in my previous app, its setting the whole view to my image, and then being able to have it like the android gallery with swiping between images

Comment: i have a flicker app, that may help you, if you want.